# creating a reverse function

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have created a button that will display 3 more buttons how I want it but I want to know if there is a fast easy way to make a button that can basically undo that function to make the 3 created buttons disappear

```
def show_pictures():
    x =0
    while x != 3:
        x += 1
        testImage = PhotoImage(file = "C:/Users/harry/Documents/coursework/images/test.png")
        imagesize = testImage.subsample(4, 3)
        Button(main_window, image= imagesize,).grid()

showButton = Button(main_window, text="Show Friend's Pictures", command= show_pictures)
showButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
clearButton = Button(main_window, text="Clear Pictures", command= show_pictures)
clearButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
```

Comment: Just use a list to store those buttons.  Then it is easy to destroy them using the list.

Comment: Shouldnt something like `grid_forget()` also work?

Comment: i'm still pretty new how on earth would I store them in a list??

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a list to store the buttons, then it is easy to destroy those buttons using the list:

```py
buttons = [] # list to store buttons

def show_pictures():
    testImage = PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/harry/Documents/coursework/images/test.png")
    imagesize = testImage.subsample(4, 3)
    for x in range(3):
        btn = Button(main_window, image=imagesize)
        btn.grid()
        btn.image = imagesize # save reference of image to prevent from garbage collected
        buttons.append(btn) # store button to list

def clear_pictures():
    # destroy all buttons in list
    for btn in buttons:
        btn.destroy()
    # clear the button list
    buttons.clear()

showButton = Button(main_window, text="Show Friend's Pictures", command=show_pictures)
showButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
clearButton = Button(main_window, text="Clear Pictures", command=clear_pictures)
clearButton.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)
```

Comment: ohhhhhhh I see! Thank you! also while doing this do you know if it is possible to assign each button a different grid value?

Comment: What grid value you want for the buttons?

Comment: so for example if I wanted them to be displayed in a 3x3 grid??

Comment: would I just apply a value to like "X" and loop a count? and apply it to the row and column?

Comment: You can use `x` to calculate the `row` and `column`. For 3x3 grid, `row, column = divmod(x, 3)`.